# Configuration property "dialect" is not defined

Tags: node.js, config

I'm having trouble setting up a project with the config npm package.

My config.js looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, SENDGRID_API_KEY } = process.env;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const config = {
 development: {
   username: DB_USERNAME,
   password: DB_PASSWORD,
   database: "database_development",
   host: DB_HOST,
   dialect: "postgres",
   sendgrid: {
     base_url: 'https://localhost:3002',
     sendgrid_api_key: SENDGRID_API_KEY,
     sender_email: '',
     enabled: true,
   },
 },
 test: {
   username: DB_USERNAME,
   password: DB_PASSWORD,
   database: "database_test",
   host: DB_HOST,
   dialect: "postgres",
   sendgrid: {
     base_url: 'https://localhost:3002',
     sendgrid_api_key: SENDGRID_API_KEY,
     sender_email: '',
     enabled: true,
   },
 },
 production: {
   username: DB_USERNAME,
   password: DB_PASSWORD,
   database: "database_production",
   host: DB_HOST,
   dialect: "postgres",
   sendgrid: {
     base_url: 'https://localhost:3002',
     sendgrid_api_key: SENDGRID_API_KEY,
     sender_email: '',
     enabled: true,
   },
 }
};

module.exports = config[env];
```

In 1 service driver file I have the following line:

`const dialect = config.get('dialect');`

I get the following error: "Error: Configuration property "dialect" is not defined".

I also tried using 'development.dialect' but that doesn't help either.

Is it possible that the `require('config');` doesn't work?

In my Sequelize's index.js file I've got
`const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js');` and that seems to work fine.

Comment: did you use [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package?

Comment: @AliShefaee Yes, I'm using the npm config package. But the example that they provided us with unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This github repository provides a good example of using [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package.
https://github.com/basarbk/tdd-nodejs
**Notes:**

1. for diffrent configs, you must have a file named whatever you use for `NODE_ENV`. for example for `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index"` create a file called `production.js`
   check config folder in root directory
2. if you are using window you should use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Comment: Thank you! Renaming the config file to development.js fixed it